# vagrant cannot connect other service and hosts

Tags: laravel, vagrant, homestead

After I received this error on my new vagrant:

```
Connection could not be established with host smtp.gmail.com :stream_socket_client(): unable to connect to tcp://smtp.gmail.com:587 (Connection timed out)
```

I checked all answers but still I have this problem.

I checked this address by:

```
 telnet smtp.gmail.com 587
```

And the result was :

```
Trying 74.125.71.108...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection timed out
```

but wen I connect to a server this works without problem.
So I think my vagrant cannot send any request to special ports!
When I test it with this:

```
 telnet google.com 80
```

the result was:

```
Trying 172.217.17.78...   
Connected to google.com.  
Escape character is '^]'.
```

So, How can I fix this?

Comment: I don't know how to fix your problem but i do remember that you can specifiy port maps in your homestead yaml. https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/homestead#ports. Have you checked you haven't rebound a port number or directed traffic elsewhere?

Comment: @Spholt it was because of my VPN :( nothing else!

Comment: Glad you sorted it out :)